# How to use void QTextStream::setRealNumberNotation

Tags: qt

For a purpose I need to use *void QTextStream::setRealNumberNotation(RealNumberNotation notation)*. I looked at so-called *Docs* for it, but there is no example for beginners! ([It's here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#setRealNumberNotation))

For example:

```
QString ss;
QTextStream (&ss);
 // here how to use it
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of what `setRealNumberNotation` does and how you can use it

```
QString mystring;
QTextStream bla(&mystring);
bla.setRealNumberNotation(QTextStream::ScientificNotation);
bla << 0.000123;
qDebug() << mystring;
bla.setRealNumberNotation(QTextStream::FixedNotation);
mystring.clear();
bla << 0.000123;
qDebug() << mystring;
```

This prints out the following:

> "1.230000e-04"
>
> "0.000123"

Some more Details about the options for `setRealNumberNotation`. The Qt Documentation lists [3 Options](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextstream.html#RealNumberNotation-enum)

- ScientificNotation # Scientific notation
- FixedNotation # Fixed-point notation
- SmartNotation # Scientific or fixed-point notation

SmartNotation uses the one which makes most sense like `printf()` `%g` conversion specifier. If you want to know how `printf` decides what makes most sense read the [printf documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf)

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked. :) (+1 + answer_up_vote) :D

Comment: Thank you. Please have a look at these:

`QString s;
QTextStream ss(&s);
ss.setRealNumberNotation(QTextStream::SmartNotation);
ss << 1000000;
result_box -> setText(s);`
Here the result is: **1000000**
But in this one:

`QString s;
double d = 1000000;
QTextStream ss(&s);
ss.setRealNumberNotation(QTextStream::SmartNotation);
ss << d;
result_box -> setText(s);`
The result is: **1e+06** !!!

Why? And how to solve it please?

Comment: Thanks for your answer.